# Trouble saving to json file with php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, loops

Forgive me, I am still learning php and jquery. I am trying to save changes to a json file from data attributes.

I have a .json file below

```
[{
    "name": "test1",
    "value": "1",
    "ID": ""
 },
 {
    "name": "test1",
    "value": "1",
    "ID": ""
 },
 {
     "name": "test2",
     "value": "1",
     "ID": ""
 }]
```

I load the file like this:

```
    $str_data = file_get_contents("data.json");
    $data = json_decode($str_data, true);
    foreach($data as $key => $val)
        echo "<li><a data-num='". $val['value'] ."'>". $val['value'] ."</a></li>";
```

I can change the data attributes like this:

```
$('li a').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = +$(this).attr("data-num");
    console.log(value);
    value = value + 1;
    console.log(value);
    $(this).attr('data-num', value);
    $(this).text(value);
});
```

This is were I'm stuck. I can I save/update the .json file with the new values based upon the updated data attributes?

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'save_to_json.php',
        success: function(data){
            // do something on success
        },
        error: function(){
            // do something on error
        }
    });
```

Comment: you have no `data` attribute in your ajax call, so you're not sending anything to the server except for the POST itself.

Comment: `var value = +$(this).attr("data-num");` Why are you doing this? Smells fishy.